# adb devices ( on android host ) shows no device

Tags: android, usb, adb

I want to use adb on android - on the device it is installed, but shows an empty list

```
shell@android:/ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 

shell@android:/ $
```

I see the device with lsusb.

```
shell@android:/ $ lsusb
18d1:4ee2 (bus 2, device 6)
```

ADB usb shows "no device found"

```
shell@android:/ $ adb usb
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5038 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: device not found
```

I tried with several (client) devices - all the same - must be a general problem. I am able to execute stuff with root permissions if needed.

Comment: did you add the udev rule for the device?

Comment: there is not even udev in /etc - but as far as I know if the rules are not there - I can see the devices ( with ?????? ) but am missing permissions

Comment: probably you are right. Silly question, did you enabled the developer options on the device?

Comment: As far as I understand, you are running the above commands on your Android device (`shell@android`). Please correct me if I'm wrong. Why are you trying to do this ? Objective of doing so ?

Comment: I want to issue adb commands from one android device to another

Comment: @ligi, The above procedure is working fine for me, Device1 (BeagleBoard XM) and Device2 (Sony Xperia M) connected via USB. You can try using adb over TCP/IP.

Comment: I need to use a cable - does your beagle-board run android?

Comment: Yes my Board is running Android 4.0.3 and Phone running 4.1.2. You might want see the `adb version` for both. I'm able to reproduce your issue when my phone is not USB debugging enabled even though connected! Please see: http://pastebin.com/aB2uqTTU

Comment: thanks for the info! that confirmes for me that it must be possible. My adb version looks good ( 1.0.31 ) - do you have /etc/udev ?

Comment: Yes, Definitely possible!. Both my devices are not having `/etc/udev`. Dev1 has root permission, Dev2 is not rooted. Suggestion : Edit your question as to what devices are you using. May help.

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling and re-enabling the USB debug option, since the latest Android version the phone will show a prompt asking you if you trust the computer trying to ADB-connect to the device otherwise it'll never show up in that list (nor in Eclipse DMBS).

Sometimes those auth get stuck and turning that option off then on seems to help, or at least it did so for me a couple of times

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have enabled 'USB Debug' on your device, and that you have the drivers for your device installed on your computer (if applicable).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to apply the 'Google USB Driver' for your specific device on your computer. The driver is located under your android-sdk/extras directory. If it's not there you need to download it from the Android SDK manager under the Extras category.

Answer (score 1):

I just use Droid @ screen it's comfortable and easy to use.
It offers Restarting ADB without using command lines and it's also good on android presentation 
heres the link http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/download/ download the latest version which is Version 1.0.1

Comment: I do not think this will run on android

Comment: but I cannot use it for my problem as it does not run on android

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happend to me when i plugged my phone to my friend's laptop who has same phone.So what i did was,i uninstalled his driver and reinstalled using my phone.It worked,and adb devices showd my device :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to issue commands from one android device to another android device, as mentioned in the comments, then you need some sort of tcp connection between them. This can be done if they are both on the same network (Wifi/LAN).

1. Install this app on the target: [ADB Manager](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=adb&fdid=com.matoski.adbm) [f-droid.org].
2. Then from the other device do a `adb connect <targetip>:<targetport>`

Note: You require root access on the target.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to use wifi and need root. There must be a way to do it without as one commenter on the question also confirmed

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no such feature available. But you can surely `list down the attached devices and communicate with them`.

```
    UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
...  
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
UsbDevice device = deviceList.get("deviceName");
```

**Reference:**

[USB Host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)

Comment: thanks! but this is not it - used different cables and the very same cable is working on my computer

Comment: @ligi: do you have any IDE like eclipse or android studio installed?

Comment: how should I on the android tablet?

Comment: @ligi: do you mean to say you are firing the commands on tablet which is attached to other devices?

Comment: thanks - but this is really not of help as this is not my problem

Comment: @ligi: what exactly do you want to achieve? why do you want to fire adb commands?

Comment: I want to install apps on the other device

Answer (score 1):

Go to SDK MANAGER in folder EXTRAS install GOOGLE USB DRIVER, if you use Windows 8 and you trying debug in Nexus devices you change your Connection USB to PTP(Camera) and enable USB DEBUG.

Reconnect your device.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try xda and see if the support libraries are available for that, but I am 99.9% sure you need to be rooted on the host android device. If you are rooted there is a and adb option available. If you are not then when you are  in a normal boot stage on the client you can use adb shell on host for sure that requires no root but only supports wifi.